# node-jsdom with loop does't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to scrape data from a series HTML pages.
For the access, there are some parameters consist queries.
These parameters are saved into json. and the son written like this way.

```
[
{"NM":"bla", "Code":"a12312"},
{"NM":"blabla", "Code":"a11231"},
{"NM":"dog", "Code":"b12311"},
...]
```

and next one is code of parsing1.js

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var schCD = require('./ggElemCD.json');

for(i in schCD){
jsdom.env("http://www.~~skipped~~&HG_CD="+schCD[i].HG_CD+"~~skipped~~", ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
       function(errors, window){
    var tObj= window.$('.TableType1 tbody tr:last td');
    console.log( "Name : "+schCD[i].HG_NM);
    console.log( "Code : "+schCD[i].HG_CD);

    var completeObj = {
        "HG_name": schCD[i],
        "HG_CD": schCD[i].HG_CD,
        "G1st_m" : tObj.get(0).innerHTML,
        "G1st_f" : tObj.get(1).innerHTML,
        "G2nd_m" : tObj.get(3).innerHTML,
        "G2nd_f" : tObj.get(4).innerHTML,
        "G3rd_m" : tObj.get(6).innerHTML,
        "G3rd_f" : tObj.get(7).innerHTML,
        "G4th_m" : tObj.get(9).innerHTML,
        "G4th_f" : tObj.get(10).innerHTML,
        "G5th_m" : tObj.get(12).innerHTML,
        "G5th_f" : tObj.get(13).innerHTML,
        "G6th_m" : tObj.get(15).innerHTML,
        "G6th_f" : tObj.get(16).innerHTML,
        "sp_m" : tObj.get(18).innerHTML,
        "sp_f" : tObj.get(19).innerHTML
    }
    console.log("value1 : "+completeObj.G1st_m);
    console.log("value2 : "+completeObj.G1st_f);
});
}
```

If the for-syntax is removed and the HG_CD put into this code manually , It works properly. However, When I insert a for-syntax, node print out error messages.

```
/Users/Snark/Dev/parsing/parsing1.js:8
    var tObj= window.$('.TableType1 tbody tr:last td');
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
    at Object.done (/Users/Snark/Dev/parsing/parsing1.js:8:18)
    at reportInitError (/Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:384:12)
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:220:9
    at Request._callback (/Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js:159:64)
    at self.callback (/Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/request.js:820:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

Comment: If `window` is undefined, there probably is an error passed as well, can you post it? I mean the error (in your case named errors) passed by the `jsdom.env` callback. How many items are in your array? Are you sure all of them work? Regardless of all of this, you shouldn't start this on parallel, better use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 210.102.102.210:80]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '210.102.102.210',
  port: 80 }

Comment: This error message passed over thousand times. and yes, I'm sure about that. but anyway, I'll try to both ways. Thanx.
Can you explains that error message?

Comment: My guess is still the same: you shouldn't do this in parallel, this is most probably related to the high number of simultaneous requests.

Comment: Yes, could replicate this with the ip in your comments. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I did it just now. It works brilliantly except for a error at 21th loop. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to deal with the error message : /Users/Snark/Dev/parsing/parsing3.js:21 "G1st_m" : tObj.get(0).innerHTML, TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at Object.done (/Users/Snark/Dev/parsing/parsing3.js:21:40) at /Users/Snark/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:271:18 at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9) at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)

Comment: Yes, i think you should include some checking for `tObj` and how many elements do actually match your selector. Right now you are expecting to always find 20 matches. Seems like this is not the case for 21th item in your array.

Comment: Also, since this is your first question on SO, remember to [mark answers as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) once your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is related to the simultaneous requests, since you seem to to have a hight number of those, you should wait for your requests to complete before making another request to the same server. Here's how to accomplish it [using the async library](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var async = require("async");
var schCD = require('./ggElemCD.json');


async.eachSeries(schCD, function(item, callback){

    jsdom.env(
        "http://www.~~skipped~~&HG_CD=" + item.HG_CD + "~~skipped~~", 
        ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        function(err, window){

            var tObj= window.$('.TableType1 tbody tr:last td');

            console.log( "Name : " + item.HG_NM);
            console.log( "Code : " + item.HG_CD);

            var completeObj = {
                "HG_name" : item,
                "HG_CD"   : item.HG_CD,
                "G1st_m"  : tObj.get(0).innerHTML,
                "G1st_f"  : tObj.get(1).innerHTML,
                "G2nd_m"  : tObj.get(3).innerHTML,
                "G2nd_f"  : tObj.get(4).innerHTML,
                "G3rd_m"  : tObj.get(6).innerHTML,
                "G3rd_f"  : tObj.get(7).innerHTML,
                "G4th_m"  : tObj.get(9).innerHTML,
                "G4th_f"  : tObj.get(10).innerHTML,
                "G5th_m"  : tObj.get(12).innerHTML,
                "G5th_f"  : tObj.get(13).innerHTML,
                "G6th_m"  : tObj.get(15).innerHTML,
                "G6th_f"  : tObj.get(16).innerHTML,
                "sp_m"    : tObj.get(18).innerHTML,
                "sp_f"    : tObj.get(19).innerHTML
            };

            console.log("value1 : " + completeObj.G1st_m);
            console.log("value2 : " + completeObj.G1st_f);

            callback(err);
        }
    );
}, function (err){

    console.log("Done.");
    err && console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanx again, you really impressed this newbie.